# Change the search engine used by about:home in Firefox

Tags: firefox, search-engines

Firefox's default home or start page provides a search engine with some snippets below it. Is there any way to customize the search engine used through `about:config` or some other configuration file?

`localStorage["search-engine"]` sometimes gets reset, possibly after an update. I would like to avoid creating a Greasemonkey script that scripts on `about:home`. If an extension exist to fulfil the task, I'd be happy too.

I'm using Firefox from Kubuntu 11.04 if that matters.

Answer (score 5):

You may want to use [Firefox with Bing](http://www.firefoxwithbing.com/)

> Bing will be set as your homepage and search engine.

Answer (score 2):

You can modify the chromeappsstore.sqlite database file inside your profile folder to change the search engine used for about:home.  It's not a text-based configuration file, but it's pretty easy to modify with the right set of tools.

You have to modify the emoh.:moz-safe-about scope in the webappsstore2 table. The key is search-engine and the value determines the search engine for that page.

The value has a name and a url.  The name can be anything and the URL will replace *searchTerms* with whatever you type into the search box.

I used the [SQLite Manager Addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/) to play with this setting, but there are other tools available.

Isn't it better to just change the home page?

Comment: That's the same thing as localStorage: `sqlite3 webappstore.sqlite`, query `select * from webappsstore2 where scope='emoh.:moz-safe-about' and key='search-engine';`. Changing the home page is a possibility, but I prefer this one.

Answer (score 2):

I just went through this trying to undo the yahoo search engine that the pdfforge toolbar installs.

Easiest way is probably to install [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) (useful for so many things), and do the following:

- go to about:home
- open the Firebug Console tab
- type in (all on one line, shown here for clarity):

  ```
  localStorage['search-engine']=JSON.stringify({
    name:"Google",
    searchUrl:
       "http://www.google.com/search?ie=UTF-8&oe=utf-8&q=_searchTerms_"})
  ```

where the `name` property is the search engine name, and `searchUrl` is the appropriate URL, with the magic token `_searchTerms_` being replaced by the keywords you type into the Firefox search box.

Then reload about:home and try again.

I got to this answer by looking at the source HTML code for the about:home page, which loads chrome://browser/content/aboutHome.js that contains code to access `localStorage['search-engine']` and use it to update the `window.location.href` based on the `searchUrl` and what you type into the search box.

Comment: This does not prevent Firefox upgrades from fiddling with this setting.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like there might be a solution on the [Mozilla Support page](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/779082).
Click Tools>Web Developer>Scratchpad, enter 
`javascript:{localStorage["search-engine"]="{\"name\":\"[SEARCH ENGINE NAME HERE]\",\"searchUrl\":\"[SEARCH URL (with _searchTerms_ placeholder)]\"}";void(0);}`

 and click Execute>Run. Also, on the `about:config` page change `browser.search.defaultenginename`.

Comment: @kino, does your Firefox indeed show Tools, For website authors, Sandbox? Mine (on a Mac) uses names like described in that forum post: Tools, Web Developer, Scratchpad.

Comment: @Arjan Translation differences. Thanks, fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Tools -> Options, and under 'Home Page' put http://www.bing.com/ or whatever other search engine you might want to use.